# What does the `.select` method do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

I don't know what it does. It's there in many programs. I've never really used it. Could someone clarify, with examples, please?

```
arr = [15, 20, 132, 144, 100, 101, 34]
s = Proc.new { |x| x<100 }
new = arr.select(&s)
```

^ The specific snippet I was talking about.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select It returns an array of elements from the collection which meet the conditions specified in the block passed to it.

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain what you don't understand about it, or what about it is confusing, etc. Otherwise, the best resource is the link Michael posted.

Comment: @muistooshort I've edited my question. Thanks to the downvoters for not telling me what the issue was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) is part of the Enumerable module, something common to Array, Hash, and a few other container-like structures. It's worth looking around in that module to see the other methods available because there's a lot of them, many quite powerful.

When learning Ruby the one thing you'll want to have on hand at all times is a bookmark to the [Ruby core documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/) or an [equivalent reference of some kind](http://apidock.com/ruby). This helps considerably because it will introduce you to very useful methods you wouldn't otherwise discover.